# Air App - Slow on Android, Super Fast on iOS

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

We have a peculiar problem if anyone has run into anything similar. We have a fairly large mobile app, built with Apache Flex 4.10 and Air 3.8. Runs beautifully on iOS. Screens are quick to load, scrolling is smooth and the app is almost desktop like. However, on an Android device, it runs painfully slow. Same codebase, both modern devices, everything same. It takes about 4 times as long to run on android as on an iOS device. Any ideas?

Comment: We need more information. What Android devices have you tested on? What does the app do? Does the app handle large images or video? Those kinds of things.

Comment: Tested on an year old iPad vs Samsung Galaxy tab 3 10.1 which is barely a month old.

Comment: The app is a Flex app, fairly large, but runs smoothly on iPad, and about 3-4 times slower on the galaxy tab 3.

Comment: Have you tested it on any other Android devices? I had issues with a Samsung Tab 8.something last year on an app I built but it was fine on other devices. Samsung's custom flavor of Android hurts performance at times.

Comment: Josh, see answer below. Issue is specific to Galaxy Tab 3 10.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue turns out is specific to Galaxy Tab 3 10.1. Same app runs significantly faster on a much older beat up Samsung Galaxy Note 2.

Other folks are running into the same issue. (http://forums.adobe.com/message/5773513) . This device ships with an Intel based chip. Air is not supported on Intel x86 based Androids (atleast from their tech specs) http://www.adobe.com/products/air/tech-specs.html

===============
Android

ARMv7 processor with vector FPU, minimum 550MHz, OpenGL ES 2.0, H.264 and AAC HW decoders
Android™ 2.3 and above
256MB of RAM

===============

Really not sure what other folks are doing to combat this, The galaxy tab is probably going to be among the most popular Android devices this holiday season. Does anyone have a similar experience?

Comment: Interesting find. I never even thought about it shipping with an x86 processor. I'm interested to know if there is a solution as well

Answer (score 0):

When an AIR app is exported to iOS, it is compiled to native code.  The Android version is compiled to the AVM bytecodes and is interpreted.  This is probably the difference in performance.

I know there have been some requests to compile AIR apps to native Android code, no idea what plans are in place for this.

Comment: The difference would not be that significant. In general, apps run nearly as fast on Android as they do on iOS for me.

Comment: Recently I tried to run the same short AIR app (Mapquest API) on an IPhone 5s and a Samsung Galaxy S4. The Galaxy S4 was way slower than the IPhone 5S, even zoom was painfully slow on the Android device.

I am wondering if the Samsung Galaxy S4 higher resolution slows down the operation of the app in some way.